# Change a Tag's Class through getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the class of all elements with a tag 'input' by using getElementsByTagName. I dont know how to change it's class.I'd tried something but it does'nt work.Please help me.

```
var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(i = 0;i < mylist.length; i++){

    //it doesnt work
    myList[i].className = "btn btn-success";
}
```

Comment: Explain what doesn't work, and post a demo to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop over `myList`, not `mylist`, as such:

```
var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    //it does work
    myList[i].className = "btn btn-success";
}
```